# Kafka Connect: could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm following [this tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) which is used for both Linux and Windows. At [Step 7](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnect) I'm getting a Java exception while trying to run:

```
>bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config\connect-standalone.properties config\connect-file-source.properties config\connect-file-sink.properties
```

The exception is:

> [2019-05-13 13:00:20,145] WARN could not get type for name
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleListener from any class loader
>   (org.reflections.Reflections) org.reflections.ReflectionsException:
>   could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
>           at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
>           at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
>           at org.reflections.Reflections.(Reflections.java:126)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.(DelegatingClassLoader.java:400)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:299)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:237)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:185)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:178)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.(Plugins.java:61)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:78)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
>           ... 9 more

I'm working on Windows.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @MeganClerc no, I just left it and took a Linux machine.

Comment: Could you share instructions how to install Kafka with MongoDb connector?

Comment: @MeganClerc sure: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-the-mongodb-connector-for-apache-kafka-and-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 1):

So I had json data in my `test.txt` file and ran the above command to get output in `test.sink.txt` file. I faced the same error mentioned above but when I checked the `test.sink.txt` file surprisingly the json data was written there by kafka. I had few json records in `test.txt` file that were incorrect and those were omitted in the output sink file.

The names of the input/output file which in this case are `test.txt`/`test.sink.txt` can be changed in the properties file that we give in the arguments of above command.

> **TLDR**: Even though the cmd shows the stack-trace/warning , the functionality seems to be working. Data goes from input file to topic
>   to output file.